# Adding new users from terminal session

Tags: linux, users, accounts

Is there a way to add a new user from the terminal AND have the system setup their user profile? ie, create their home DIR and add then to the sudoers file? I'd like to be able to do this without them having to log in via the GUI. This is an Ubuntu 14.04 system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

```
$ sudo adduser --ingroup sudo foo
```

this will create user `foo` and add them to the `sudo` group which should already be in the `sudoers` file.

if you need more fine-grained control about what goes into the `sudoers` file and are not afraid of interactivity (and `vi`!), just do:

```
$ sudo adduser foo
$ sudo visudo
```

Comment: thanks - I ran useradd, instead of adduser, which makes you have to setup everything manually. problem solved thanks:)